# PHP: Column count doesn't match when importing CSV file with empty cells/columns

Tags: php, csv

I have a code that will allow users to import/insert data into database from the CSV file. the problem is that if there is an empty columns or cells from the CSV file, it will display an error telling me that the **column count doesn't match value count at row 1**. I tried to assign a value in the empty cells/columns of the CSV file and it successfully uploaded. How can I allow the users to upload a CSV file even if there's an empty columns/cells? Below is my code.

```
            if ($handle) {
                $counter = 0;
                $sql ="INSERT IGNORE INTO bill_of_materials(allotment_code, category_name, activity, quantity, unit, description, end_unit_quantity, unit_cost, regular_labor_cost, end_unit_labor_cost, type, batch) VALUES";

                while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

                    $sql .= "('".implode("', '", explode("|", addslashes(str_replace('"', '', $line))))."'),";
                    $counter++;
                }

                $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1);

                 if (mysqli_query($new_conn, $sql) === TRUE) {

                    $message = 1;

                } else {

                    echo mysqli_error($new_conn);
                }
                fclose($handle);
```

here is my table:
[image: my table]

and here's the csv file:
[image: csv file]

Comment: Wrong slash, bro `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump` shold be `\\`

Comment: thanks for your answer. that code is not for uploading a CSV file but for database backup. my problem is in the uploading the csv. I edited my code to avoid confusion.

Comment: It is a big piece of code. Do you think we have so much time here?

Comment: @Piterden I'm sorry about that. I edited my code again.

Comment: How about changing `!==` to `!=`?

Comment: Where is your CSV? Maybe it is broken?

Comment: @david thanks for your answer but I still get an error.

Comment: Would just `while ($line = fgets($handle))` work? Show your CSV @FrancisDeGracia

Comment: @Piterden I updated my question with my csv file photo and table. `the while ($line = fgets($handle))` didn't work too.

Comment: I meant the raw CSV file. Why do we need your table? Btw, you could export JSON and avoid those troubles.

Comment: @Piterden I will try the JSON. thanks for your answer.